# How to parse JSON url of api data and display in div

Tags: json

I want to get the data from Json url api page, how can i get this, please help me in this regards

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#driver").click(function(event){
        $.getJSON('http://globalmetals.xignite.com/xGlobalMetals.json/GetLondonFixing?Symbol=XAU&Currency=USD', function(data) {
            var json = $.parseJSON(data);
            $('#stage').html('<p> Outcome: ' + json.Outcome + '</p>');
            $('#stage').append('<p>Message : ' + json.Message+ '</p>');
            $('#stage').append('<p> Name: ' + json.Name+ '</p>');
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: `$.getJSON` parses the JSON for you, you don't need to call `$.parseJSON`.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `$.getJSON`, the data is already parsed for you, it's wrong to call `$.parseJSON`.

```
$.getJSON('http://globalmetals.xignite.com/xGlobalMetals.json/GetLondonFixing?Symbol=XAU&Currency=USD', function(json) {
    $('#stage').html('<p> Outcome: ' + json.Outcome + '</p>');
    $('#stage').append('<p>Message : ' + json.Message+ '</p>');
    $('#stage').append('<p> Name: ' + json.Name+ '</p>');
});
```